# Is this Loopback nested query as filter possible, how?

Tags: mongodb, loopbackjs, axios

I'm going to be completely honest, I have no idea where to really start on this. Basic filters with where are easy, but I'm not familiar with loopback enough to sort this out.

I have 3 models like (this is just a crude example):

**User**

```
{
    "id": "string",
    "name": "string",
    "username": "string",
    "email": "string"
}
```

**ProjectUser**

```
{
    "id": "string",
    "user": "string",
    "project": "string",
    "permissions": "object"
}
```

**Project**

```
{
    "id": "string",
    "name": "string"
}
```

I need to be able to grab all Projects a user is associated with. This means using the user.id to get all projectusers and then projects based on those results project ids.

Looking for the right setup to go in here:

```
getProjects: (userId, success) => {
  axios.get(`${url}Projects`, {
    params: {
      filter:
        ???
    }
  })
  .then((response) => {
    success(response);
  });
}
```

So, is this possible or will I need to do it in separate requests?

**EDIT!!!**

The axios request above is just a loopback json.stringofied parameter for the request.

Like:

```
getProjects: (userId, success) => {
  axios.get(`${url}Projects`, {
    params: {
      filter:
        JSON.stringify(
        {
          where: {
            id: id
          }
        }
      )
    }
  })
  .then((response) => {
    success(response);
  });
}
```

Or inline:

```
${url}Projects?filter={"where":{"id":2}}
```

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Querying-data.html#using-stringified-json-in-rest-queries

Comment: It is possible.  I am not familiar with the syntax you are using above, but the way you "join" these collections is to use [MongoDb aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/).  Study the documentation a bit.  You can also find other SO questions on aggregation.  Pay particular attention to the [$lookup stage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup).

Comment: I've updated the question to include reference and explanation of the axios request. It's basically JSON that gets stringified and sent as the filter object in loopback.

Comment: If you setup the relations correctly, including a HasManyThrough on the User model (User has many Projects through ProjectUser), you should be able to query projects by user using `GET /api/users/:id/projects. Alternatively, you could get the user with the included projects using `GET /api/users/:id?filter[include][projects]`. It looks like you are trying to filter using the properties of a related model. I'm unsure if Loopback supports that for mongodb. Read more on their [github issue](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/517).